# Both including and importing std

Tags: c++, std, c++-modules

I have a C++ module that imports `std`:

```cpp
// MyModule.ixx
export module MyModule;

import std;

export namespace MyNamespace {
   class MyClass : std::monostate {};
}
```

I want to import the module in another file:

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <QtCore/QDebug>

import MyModule;

auto main(int argc, char **argv) -> int {
   qDebug() << "test";
   MyNamespace::MyClass A;
}
```

This gives a compilation error:

```
main.cpp(7,25): fatal  error C1117: unrecoverable error importing module 'std': symbol 'monostate' has already been defined
```

If I remove `#include <QtCore/QDebug>` and `qDebug() << "test";`, the program compiles fine. So it seems that `#include <QtCore/QDebug>` indirectly includes `std::monostate`, and that it conflicts with the one imported by `import std;` in `MyModule.ixx`.

How can I resolve this? Can't I `import std` when somewhere else in my program the standard library is `#include`d?

Comment: I tried same on MSVC, it gives an internal compiler error on `constexpr` specification! starting with `import std;` removes the issue in my code.

Comment: @dalfaB Do you mean that doing `import std;` at the beginning of `main.cpp` solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by importing `<variant>` instead of `std`:

```cpp
// MyModule.ixx
export module MyModule;

import <variant>;

export namespace MyNamespace {
   class MyClass : std::monostate {};
}
```